# How I can load data from the database whose role is 1 which is the admin

Tags: database, laravel, admin, laravel-8, roles

This is the current code that loads all the users in the database. In the role 1 is admin and 2 are the normal users. So how can I return only the admin whit a role of 1?

```html
@foreach ($users as $key => $user)
    <tr>
        <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
        <td>
            @if ($user->status == 1)
                Active
            @else
                Deactivated
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: add where condition role  is 1.User::where('role_id',1)->all(); also please post user  and role  table relation .are you managing role seperately

Answer (score 0):

In controller your can do like this

```
      $users=User::where('role',1);
```

And in view

```
            @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
                <tr>
                    <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" 
                    name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                    <td>@if ($user->status==1) Active
                        
                    @else Deactivated
                        
                    @endif
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                 @endforeach
```

Or else in view it self you can write a logic like

```
         @php
             $users=$users->where('role',1)
         @endphp
         @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
                <tr>
                    <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" 
                    name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                    <td>@if ($user->status==1) Active
                        
                    @else Deactivated
                        
                    @endif
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                 @endforeach
```